# undefined reference returning exit status

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

Error returned at line 27 (line beginning with "charges") stating "undeclared reference (for the calculateCharge, to my best guess) and compiler notes says "ld returned 1 exit status"
I can't for the life of me get what need to change.

```
float calculateCharge(float);

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");

  int car;
  int num_cars;
  float total_charges = 0;
  float total_hours = 0;

  printf("How many cars?\n\n");      //prompt
  scanf("%d", &num_cars);            //prompt

  float hours [num_cars + 1];        //declaring parallel arrays
  float charges [num_cars + 1];

  for (car=1; car<=num_cars; car++)
  {
      printf("How many hours for car #%d?", car);     //prompt
      scanf("%f", &hours[car]);                       //input hours
      charges [car] = calculateCharge(hours [car]);
      total_charges = total_charges + charges [car];
      total_hours = total_hours + hours [car];
  }
  printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t", "Car", "Hours", "Charge");

  for (car = 1; car <=num_cars; car++)
  {
       printf("\n%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", car, hours[car], charges[car]);
  }

printf("\n%s\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", "Total", total_hours, total_charges);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a forced base-one indexing on your arrays will only get seasoned coders frustrated, and newbie coders confused. Please don't do it, use "normal" zero-base like everyone else.

Comment: As for your problem, where do you implement (*define*) the `calculateCharge` function? You *do* implement it somewhere?

Comment: You have a *declaration* for `calculateCharge()`. But where's the definition of `calculateCharge()`?

Comment: In addition to what others have said,, this is a linker error, not a compile error. There's nothing syntactically wrong with your code. The linker is basically saying, "You're calling this `calculateCharge` function, but I have no idea where the code for it is". You'll need to create a function body for `calculateCharge` or not use it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies all.  I'm an electrical engineer by trade studying for an IT degree. I now understand that my declaration does no good with the definition.  Any ideas on how to work this out? Not asking for the answer, just a nudge in the right direction.  Cheers all. =)

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

Comment: Woops.  I see from my notes I left out the function entirely.  Thanks again everyone!  Got it working =)

Comment: float calculateCharge (float hours)
{
    float charge;
    hours = ceil(hours);
    if (hours <=3)
    {
        charge = 2.00;
    }else
    {
        charge = 2.00 + (hours - 3) * 0.50;
        if (charge > 10.00)
        {
            charge = 10.00;
        }
    }
    return charge;

Comment: You could very well answer to your own question and even accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is the entirety of your code, you have provided a forward declaration of what the signature of `calculateCharge` is, so the compiler can generate the code to call it (once it knows where the actual definition is), but you haven't provided that actual definition.